# Multilingual entities with inheritance?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, multilingual

I need some multilingual entities in our application and I want to know what are the best practice for that.

Currently it solved with an 1:n relation, because there general information and language specific fields.

Is it possible and a good idea to use entity inheritance for that? So I can change always the general part on an object?

Example (pseudo code)

```
class Product {
    public $id;
    public $status;
}

class ProductDetails extends Product {
    public $language;
    public $name;
    public $description;
}
```

I hope my explanation helps a bit to make clear what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a good idae, because inheritance is meant to be static. As soon as you want a new locale, you will have to add a new inheritance element in your map. As a contrary, a 1:n relation is good, as it grows without any modification. Moreover, adding a field with a  **single** table inheritance means ading a field for **every** entity in this table.
Better to use oneToMany :)

Comment: Another point against table inheritance is when you will want to do native queries. It will become hard/impossible to configure your ResultStMapping.